# Typographical symbol to indicate page

Tags: punctuation, typography

There are many typographical symbols, for example:

- The pilcrow (¶) is used for paragraphs.
- The asterisk, dagger and double dagger (*,†,‡) for footnotes.
- The hurricane (§) for sections.

Is there any symbol for pages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not aware of a symbol; I use **p.** or **pp.** for single or multiple pages.

(and is the section symbol really called "hurricane"? that's amusing.)

Comment: I never knew those paragraph markers were called pilcrows ...

Comment: @bamboo Unicode has three distinct pilcrows, and many fonts have additional ones. ‭ ¶  U+00B6       PILCROW SIGN; ‭ ⁋  U+204B       REVERSED PILCROW SIGN; ‭ ❡  U+2761       CURVED STEM PARAGRAPH SIGN ORNAMENT.  Just as he does with ampersands, Bringhurst advises using the nicest looking pilcrow the font contains, which is often an alternate swash character.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for that, but the only time I've seen them is when I've got Word set to 'reveal codes' and you can see them at the beginning of every line. That's the total extent of any techie knowledge I've got!

Comment: From wikipedia: The section sign (§, Unicode U+00A7, HTML entity &sect;) is a typographical character used mainly to refer to a particular section of a document. It is also called "double S", "hurricane", "sectional symbol", "the legal doughnut", signum sectiōnis.

Comment: @bamboo It is a corruption of French "paragraphe".

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer offered by Lauren Ipsum, the electronic era of document control has introduced a number of symbols for page through the requirement to mark a page break. In particular, [form feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form-feed) is used to denote the end of the current page and the start of a new page. The symbol for form feed is represented in a number of ways:

- FF
- [U+000c (unicode)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=form%20feed&preview=entity)
- ↡  [U+21a1 (unicode)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=form%20feed&preview=entity) double down-headed arrow
- ␌ [U+240c (unicode)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=form%20feed&preview=entity) form feed symbol F F
- \f (programming)